# What’s the difference between the “Indoor Walk” and “Indoor Run” workouts?

Tags: apple-watch

The Apple Watch supports workouts called Indoor Walk, Indoor Run, and Indoor Cycle, and it also has Outdoor versions of these. The [Apple Watch User Guide](https://help.apple.com/watch/#/apd36e57e00c) explains that

> Outdoor and Indoor Walk/Run/Cycle are distinct workouts because Apple Watch calculates the calorie burn differently for each. For indoor workouts, Apple Watch relies mainly on your heart rate readings for calorie estimates, but for outdoor workouts, Apple Watch works in conjunction with iPhone (which has GPS) to calculate speed and distance.

But it doesn’t explain the difference between e.g. Indoor Walk and Indoor Run. When I use a treadmill I go for long walks interspersed with some running. Which Indoor workout is more appropriate for tracking this kind of exercise?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a mixture of run and walk; go with indoor run. The sensors pick up your jogging stride differently when it knows your running so it will be more accurate when it expects your arms to be in a run position.

Comment: That’s interesting. Do you have anything in the way of a source for that?

Answer (score 0):

One difference I've learned is that there are some badges apparently locked to Indoor Run that are not achievable with Indoor Walk.

I like to go at a pace that's somewhere in-between walking and running but always choose Indoor Walk as the exercise type.  Today I chose Indoor Run (accidentally), and at the completion of my 6.25 mi run/walk received a barrage of Apple Watch notifications for unlocking new badges:

- 5K Run
- Fastest 5K
- 10K Run
- Fastest 10K

I've walked these distances and longer before, but never received these badges for equivalent indoor or outdoor walking workouts even though I'm doing the same thing.  I guess I'll choose run again next time to see if there are more badges in this category.